# Go back to the previous row using DataReader on ASP.NET (VB)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datareader

How can I go back to the `previous` row using `OleDbDataReader`.

I know that DataReader just advance to the next row using DataReader.Read(), but how can I go back to the previous row. ???!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. The DataReader API was specifically designed to only allow forward iteration. If you need the previous row, you should cache it yourself, or use something else (like dump the DataReader into a DataSet)

Comment: why not change the API to allows forward iteration ?

Comment: Because it is a very generic API, used for all kinds of data sources. For some data sources, keeping track of more than one row is very expensive (or maybe even impossible). If you want more than one row, the provided solution is to use a `DataSet`. If memory serves, it's `DataSet.Fill(dataReader)`